# Add an explanation about the difference and role of the per-site and networkwise meta to the Help center

Tags: discussion, meta, per-site-meta, help-center-proposed

I just crossed paths with a very new (and highly active) user in chat, and it turned out that he had never known about Meta - and when he tried to visit it, he clicked the featured question of the networkwide Meta on the right sidebar, and was confused that he wasn't able to find the per-site-meta question we were discussing in chat.

I looked into the Help center and realized that it only explains the concept of the per-site Meta. It doesn't even mention the networkwide Meta, much less explain the difference between the two and what's the role of each. Even more confusingly, for new users it is more likely that the per-site Meta will be relevant than the networkwide Meta, but with the current UI, it is very easy to find the networkwide Meta, while the sitewide one is relatively hidden.

I am aware that not everybody reads the Help center (it also being relatively hidden, at least for users who have been around for a while), but it would still be helpful to have a write up there which can be linked for interested new users to read. In the current state, the information is incomplete and thus misleading.

Comment: The default templates (Examples: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) seem fairly good, exactly what did you want added to each one?

Comment: @Rob these all discuss only the per-site meta. I don't see any mention of the existence of the network wide meta, much less an explanation which one exists for what purpose, how to know which one the user has currently reached, etc.

Comment: Perhaps that write-up could also explain why things that affect the entire network often get posted onto Stack Overflow's Meta instead of here

Comment: @Richard No, this is the Meta site for all the network. Meta Stack Overflow is only for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - Indeed. Which is why it's disappointing to see major *network affecting* changes announced on MSO, rather than MSE.